# How to change Flash message in Alert message in Symfony2

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I am stuck in a problem, that after execution of a action method in Symfony2 Controller , success message is come as in the form of flash message , but as per requirement i have to render these success message in the form of alert message or dialogue message .

I am trying all to do this but did't get success.

Is any idea is available regarding this issue. If available please help  me .

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the flash message you could return the value of the flash message to the twig template you're rendering after the controller did his work.

```
return $this->render('Bundle:Entity:template.html.twig', array(
    #...,
    'flashValue' => $stringThatWouldHaveBeenInTheFlashMessage
));
```

In your template you could just go and create a hidden paragraph with this value.

```
<p style="display: hidden;" id="your_hidden_value">{{ flashValue }}</p>
```

From that on you could just do this with `jQuery`

```
$(function(){
    var text = $('#your_hidden_id').val(); //get the value from that id
    alert(text);
});
```

Comment: It works fine except , var text = $('#your_hidden_id').val() , instead i have used var text = $('#your_hidden_id').text();    Thanks a lot ..